# Git clone slow?

Tags: git, ssh, clone

I just recently noticed that when I clone a new repo (regardless of size), git clone seems to hang. I've tried running in verbose mode but I don't see anything.

If I wait long enough, it eventually clones but it is way slower than it's been before.

All other git commands work just fine. I can push, pull, fetch, etc no problem. I only notice slowness when I clone.

My download speeds are just fine (80 mbps down) and I know it isn't repo specific because I can make a new, tiny repo on github and try to clone it and it takes 10+ minutes.

The only thing I can think of is if it's something with SSH. I did recently add a new SSH key. I haven't had trouble authenticating (as far as I can tell). I usually use ssh to clone, I just tried over HTTPS and I had the same slowness.

Here's a what I saw on my last successful clone:

```
Cloning into 'repo-name'...
error: ignoring template /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/gdrive/tmp0F0X6n
error: ignoring template /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/gdrive/tmplj3WUJ
error: ignoring template /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/gdrive/tmpPGME7Z
error: ignoring template /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/gdrive/tmpSbnzav
error: ignoring template /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/gdrive/tmpTer2Uf
remote: Counting objects: 172, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 172 (delta 17), reused 14 (delta 14), pack-reused 153
Receiving objects: 100% (172/172), 18.86 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: Are you cloning a repo to a google drive?  That could be a major source of slowdown.  (Try cloning to elsewhere, then moving the repo to the google drive.)

Comment: I don't understand that error message because I'm not cloning into Google Drive. The directory I am cloning into is not connected to my Google Drive in any way.

Comment: Can you include a verbose clone?

Comment: That was a verbose clone...but now I'm running npm install --verbose and I see that it hangs on the clone step
   `npm info git [ 'clone',
    npm info git   '/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github.com-repo-name-45c04fe3',
    npm info git '/var/folders/8v/s8mldnz571qb7v0w09__vv540000gq/T/npm-50934-1960caf5/git-cache-72fd485d77be/9a4c96e9a5ecae40486cab3542168740e9657535' ]`

Comment: I once has a slow clone, I quit Skype and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't clone a repository and place it on Google Drive. Git uses many file accesses and each request on a network stored location (such as Google Drive) will increase significant delays due to network latency and performance of the network server.

You should also check that `git` isn't installed/running from GDrive, as this will pull in the templates (from `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) and these are read significantly when creating a clone for the first time. You may find it's picking up something from the `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: Just answered Mr.Llama above but that's the weird thing...I'm not cloning into Google Drive.

Comment: There seem to be many references to templates in your GDrive folders though - something is reading/writing there. You can use `sudo fs_usage -w | grep gdrive` to get a list of what's being accessed from there.

Comment: Also, is 'git' running from Google Drive? It seems to be picking up the templates (normally in `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) and using them instead.

Comment: When I run that grep command, I do not get anything. Git shouldn't be running from Google Drive. I don't see any `.git` directories in Google Drive.

Comment: You'll need to run that command, then execute a clone. If you see lots of accesses to entries on `gdrive` then something is accessing it during a clone - your next step will be to try and find out what. Perhaps something has configured your environment badly and running `git` is running a wrapper script, or other `GIT_` environment variables are causing problems.

Comment: Ah thanks! Ok ran a clone and that grep command did return a few accesses to entreis on `gdrive`.

Comment: You can identify if it's the templates specifically by running `git clone --template-directory=/somewhere/else`  and seeing if that's significantly faster. If it is, you should look at the `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY` variable or if there's a symlink to the git-templates directory.

Comment: I've deleted my local Google Drive and deleted those temp files. Brew remove and install git (as well as  doctor, and update). But I still see it hang on git clone...

Comment: Did you check the GIT_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY environment variable?

Comment: Ok just noticed something else...the last 2 repo's I've cloned are both almost 20 GB's. But they shouldn't be. I cloned one previously in another location and it's well under 1 gig with the latest master.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT!! Wooot. At some point along the way, I added an init template directory to my gitconfig. Don't know why I didn't look there in the first place, but once I deleted that template, it cloned at the correct size. So all good now. Thanks for the help along the way!!

Comment: You might want to mark this answer as correct then, since it was identified as a template issue.